# error with bold font in section title with beamer

Tags: fonts, beamer, sectioning

I am getting errors when compiling a LaTeX document with the `beamer` (v3.13) class when using bold shape in a title section:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{The \textbf{Section} Title}

\begin{frame}{Testing frame}
  This is a test.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Compilation with pdflatex gives the error:

```
! Argument of \@gobble has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.5     \section{The \textbf{Section} Title}
```

The error happens when using other font variations like slanted and italic.

Also the command `\emph` used in a section title gives an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@sort #1#2->\long \def \beamer@todo 
                                           {#1}\def \beamer@ospec {}\beamer@...
l.5     \section{The \emph{Section} Title}
```

Are these known bugs or am I missing something? Is there any fix for them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to `\protect` these commands in sections

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{The \protect\textbf{Section} Title}

\begin{frame}{Testing frame}
  This is a test.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is an underlying problem with some design decisions made when `beamer` was developed. Commands with overlay abilities are regrettable not set up to be 'robust', and it is not clear how this can be remedied without breaking existing `beamer` behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

Note that [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) does a large amount of leg-work in making commands overlay aware. One drawback of this is some standard commands become fragile. You could use the `\bfseries` font switch (which is `\protect`ed by default) alternative:

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer

\begin{document}

\section{The {\bfseries Section} Title}

\begin{frame}{Testing frame}
  This is a test.
\end{frame}

\end{document}​
```

Comment: But it does not work for me when I sue ``\frametitle{\protect\textit{in vacuo}}``