# beamerarticle - problem with commands in sections

Tags: sectioning, beamerarticle

I encountered the following problem with the beamerarticle package. If I use commands like \textit{} I get the following error massage:

```
./test.tex:7: Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par Runaway argument?
{\normalfont \Large \bfseries }{\beamer@sortzeroread {\beamerx@\textit \ETC.
./test.tex:7: Paragraph ended before \@sect was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.7 \section{Test \textit{test} test}

? 
l.7 \section{Test \textit{test} test}

?
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}
\section{Test \textit{test} test}
\end{document}
```

Without the package or without the \textit{} the example works. Furthermore, if I use an optional argument in the section, it works as well, but if it contains any formatting commands. That is,

```
\section[\textit{test}]{Test \textit{test} test}
```

works, while

```
\section[test]{Test \textit{test} test}
```

doesn't.

Any ideas what is going on here or how to solve it?

Comment: This is a fragile command in a moving argument you need `\protect\textit`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\textit` is supposed to be robust: `\show\textit` produces `\protect \textit  .` But `beamerarticle` changes it into `\beamer@sortzero{\beamerx@\textit}`. :(

Comment: Closely related question: [error with bold font in section title with beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47301/3323).

Answer (score 12):

While the `\textit` command is normally robust and doesn't need protection in moving arguments (which are the arguments to `\section` and siblings, `\caption` and some others), with the `beamerarticle` package it is not robust any more.

So the answer is, with that package

```
\section{Test \protect\textit{test} test}
```

or, if you use the command in the optional argument,

```
\section[Test \protect\textit{test}]{Test \textit{test} test}
```

(the moving argument is the mandatory one, if the optional argument is missing, otherwise the optional argument).

Also the other font changing commands are not robust any more.

Note: I'm inclined to consider this a bug of `beamerarticle` (or `beamer` in general), as it's not mentioned in the user manual, while LaTeX user guides tell that `\textit` is OK in moving arguments.