# Slider ticker on beamer runs off page

Tags: beamer, sectioning, navigation, mini-frames

I am creating a presentation using the beamer class and the Singapore theme, however I have so many sections that the slide ticker bar at the top runs off the edge of the page.

Is there a way to make a second row of section names in the header, or alternatively insert a line break into the section names? I have tried following the advice here: [using \textit in \section{} with beamer class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31612/using-textit-in-section-with-beamer-class) to try and get formatting in the section to no avail, and here [How to put a line-break in section heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14008/how-to-put-a-line-break-in-section-heading) but it doesn't seem to work with beamer.

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[compres]{beamer}
\documentclass[compres]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\begin{document}

\section{Bijection to nondeterministic metric space}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction to Langevin diffusion}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\section{Twice differentiable complexity classes}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\section{Applications in 4D}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusions}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In this example, line breaking the section headings would allow the problem to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible solution: now each title is typeset inside a `\parbox`; the width of the `\parbox`es is internally calculated as the available width divided by the total number os sections.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{%
  \parbox[c][0.33cm][t]{\dimexpr(\textwidth-1.3cm)/\beamer@sectionmax\relax}{%
    \RaggedRight\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont\insertsectionhead}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Bijection to nondeterministic metric space}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{Test Frame One}
test
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction to Langevin diffusion}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\section{Twice differentiable complexity classes}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\section{Applications in 4D}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusions}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the new headline:

[image]

If your titles are too long, you could consider using the optional argument of `\section` instead:

```
\section[Title in Nav and Toc]{Title in Document}
```