# Beamer Frankfurt header runs off page

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

I'm using the Beamer Frankfurt header. When my final section has a lot of slides, the circles run off the page, so the "active" circle is not visible in much of the final section. The titles appear to be spaced equidistantly, with the final title aligned on the far right of the page. See image:
[image: beamer_header]

It seems like a better approach would be to space the titles according to the number of slides in each section. This would make it more likely that all the circles would fit on a page.

Can this be done?

Comment: We had this question here before, can’t find it though. Your `beamer` installation is old, this behavior is fixed in recent versions of `beamer`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Maybe you mean [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67118/slider-ticker-on-beamer-runs-off-page).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this problem...

Here it what I tried, and it worked perfectly fine !

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{One}
\subsection{Sec 1.1}
\begin{frame}{Title 1}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 2}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 3}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 4}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 5}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 6}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 7}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 8}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 9}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 10}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 11}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 12}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 13}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 14}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 15}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 16}
Hello !
\end{frame}


\section{Two}
\subsection{Sec 2.1}
\begin{frame}{Title 1}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 2}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 3}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 4}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 5}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 6}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 7}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 8}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 9}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 10}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 11}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 12}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 13}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 14}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 15}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 16}
Hello !
\end{frame}

\section{Three}
\subsection{Sec 3.1}
\begin{frame}{Title 1}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 2}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 3}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 4}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 5}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 6}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 7}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 8}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 9}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 10}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 11}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 12}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 13}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 14}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 15}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title 16}
Hello !
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And I got this as output :

[image: Output 1]

[image]

Maybe if you put a short example, I'see what I can do ...